# Cartesian products involving empty sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, set-partition

Let $(\Omega_i)_{i\in I}$ be a nonempty family of sets. For each $i \in I$, let $\mathcal{E}_i$ be a set of subsets of $\Omega_i$. Let

$$ \coprod_{i\in I} \mathcal{E}_i:=\bigg\{\prod_{i\in I}A_i : A_i\in\mathcal{E}_i \cup\{\Omega_i\} , 
 A_i\neq \Omega_i \text{ for finitely many }i\in I \bigg\}$$

Let $(I)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be a partition of $I$ into disjoint nonempty sets. I am trying to prove that

$$\coprod_{i\in I} \mathcal{E}_i= \coprod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \bigg( \coprod_{i\in I_\lambda} \mathcal{E}_i\bigg)$$

when identifying sets of the form $\prod_{i\in I} A_i$ $(A_i\subset\Omega_i)$ with $\prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \big( \prod_{i\in I_\lambda} A_i\big)$. I already showed $\coprod_{i\in I} \mathcal{E}_i \subset \coprod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \bigg( \coprod_{i\in I_\lambda} \mathcal{E}_i\bigg)$, but I am not sure the reverse inclusion holds if $\Omega_i =\emptyset$ for some $i$.

Is this reasoning correct? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Omega_i = \emptyset$ does not cause a problem, both sides will just be empty.

Your definition of $\coprod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \bigg( \coprod_{i\in I_\lambda} \mathcal{E}_i\bigg)$ is incomplete, as you haven't defined an $\Omega_{I_\lambda}$ for each member of $\coprod_{i\in I_\lambda} \mathcal{E}_i$ to be a subset of. If we put that to be $\bigcup \bigg( \coprod_{i\in I_\lambda} \mathcal{E}_i\bigg)$ then your equality does hold.

To show the reverse inequality note that any member $\prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} B_\lambda$ of $\coprod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \bigg( \coprod_{i\in I_\lambda} \mathcal{E}_i\bigg)$ will have, for all but finitely many $\lambda$, $B_\lambda = \Omega_{I_\lambda} = \prod_{i\in I_\lambda} \Omega_i$. So each member is of the form $\prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \big( \prod_{i\in I_\lambda} A_i\big)$ with $A_i \neq \Omega_i$ for only finitely many $i$  from only finitely many $I_\lambda$, and so it identifies with $\prod_{i\in I} A_i$ for only finitely many $A_i \neq \Omega_i$ overall.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Indeed $\coprod_{i\in I_\lambda} \mathcal{E}_i$ is a set of subsets of $ \prod_{i\in I_\lambda} \Omega_i$. The problem I see is that if $\Omega_i = \emptyset$ for some $i$, then  we can have $\prod_{i\in I_\lambda} A_i= \prod_{i\in I_\lambda} \Omega_i=\emptyset$ and yet $A_i\neq \emptyset$ for infinitely many $i\in  I_\lambda$. Hence after identification we could get $A_i \neq \Omega_i$ infinitely often. I agree that both sides will be empty, but the condition required on the index set may fail.

Comment: Sorry I meant : and yet $A_i\neq \Omega_i$ for infinitely many $i \in I_{\lambda}$.

Comment: If any one $\Omega_i = \emptyset$ then both expressions are empty and so are equal.   It doesn't matter if a member of one of these families of products is equal to a some $\prod A_i$ where infinitely many of the $A_i \neq \Omega_i$ as long as it is also equal to one where only finitely many $A_i \neq \Omega_i$. It's the actual elements that matter, not the way they are described. (Of course, that can only happen if at least one $A_i$ is empty anyway.)

Comment: Ok I see. Just to be clear, when $\Omega_i = \emptyset$ for some $i$, we have $\coprod_{i\in I} \mathcal{E}_i= \coprod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \bigg( \coprod_{i\in I_\lambda} \mathcal{E}_i\bigg)=\{\emptyset\}$ right? Not $\emptyset$.

Comment: Yes. $\{ \emptyset \}$ not $\emptyset$. I was somewhat unclear as to which expressions I was referring to at times - trying to avoid too much Tex. If any term in a product is empty. so is the product. That then makes $\emptyset$ a member of any family that the product is a member of.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption, condition, prerequisite that:

> > Let $\Omega_{i_{i \epsilon I}}$  be a nonempty family of sets.

implies, garanties that

Ω=∅ for some .

is not possible. There exists no such Ω=∅ for all ∈ that Ω=∅!

$$\not \exists \Omega_{i_{i \epsilon I}} : \Omega_{i}=∅$$

or

$$\forall \Omega_{i_{i \epsilon I}} : \Omega_{i}\not = ∅$$

Use this argument and You are done. The condition is more than that I in nonempty. This website provides some inside into the meaings of the condition:
[MathWorld Family](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Family.html). The article contains a passage that explains the details:

[image]